# lumx drop down is not working with angular-ui and bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, lumx

I am doing a project in which I am using LUMX, Angular-UI and Bootstrap as well

I am facing problem that my drop down is not working
here is code snippet.

```
<li class="dropdown" dropdown on-toggle="toggled(open)">
        <a href class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
            <i class="ti-world"></i> {{language.selected}}
        </a>
        <ul role="menu" dropdown-menu class="dropdown-menu dropdown-light fadeInUpShort">
            <li ng-repeat="(localeId, langName) in language.available">
                <a ng-click="language.set(localeId, $event)" href="#" class="menu-toggler">
                    {{langName}}
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

if I will remove lumx.js in index.html it will start working.
but still drop down of lumx will not work.

```
<div flex-item>
    <lx-select ng-model="selects.selectedCategory" placeholder="Select Category" choices="categories" floating-label>
                            <lx-select-selected>
                                {{ $selected.name }} - {{ $selected.id }}
                            </lx-select-selected>

                            <lx-select-choices>
                                {{ $choice.name }} - {{ $choice.id }}
                            </lx-select-choices>
                        </lx-select>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution.
drop down class from lumx.css and angular-ui.css was conflicting with each other.

I remove

```
.dropdown{
 }
```

css from lumx.css now my angular-ui drop down started working.